# ImageBackground doesn't accept ResizeMode

Tags: react-native

Anyone here can help me make *resizeMode* work with `<ImageBackground>`?

It gives an error that *resizeMode* is applied to `View`, which apparently doesn't support it.

But i need to find a workaround, as i find pretty complicated to use `<Image />` as a background for a block with info.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```html
<ImageBackground 
  style={[styles.image]} 
  source={{ uri: url }} 
  imageStyle={{resizeMode: 'contain'}}
>
  // other components here
</ImageBackground>
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score -3):

> NOTE: At the time I wrote this, `<ImageBackground />` was an undocumented feature not yet released. But it does exist now.

There is no `<ImageBackground />` that I'm aware of, but you can create one.

If you're trying to set an image as the background to some text, then `<Image />` is the best way. Where do you feel it's overly complicated? Something like this should work...

```
class BackgroundImage extends Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <Image 
                source={this.props.src}
                style={styles.backgroundImage}>

                    {this.props.children}

            </Image>
        )
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    backgroundImage: {
        flex: 1,
        width: null,
        height: null,
        resizeMode: 'cover'
    }
});
```

Then you'd use it like this...

```
<BackgroundImage
    src={require('./background.jpg')}>

    <Text>Your Content Goes Here!</Text>
</BackgroundImage>
```

Comment: Hi there! Thanks for the response. `<ImageBackground />` [actually exists](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/Libraries/Image/ImageBackground.js). But i will try your solution and let you know ASAP! Thanks!

Comment: Interesting, I've not found it in the docs. Is it undocumented? How did you find out about it?

Comment: here you go https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/images.html#background-image-via-nesting